# How can I monitor data usage on my router?

Tags: router, bandwidth

My ISP imposes restrictions on the data usage (upload + download), and I'd like to monitor this. There are multiple devices using internet at my home, mostly wireless. I'd like a device-wise report of data used. My router/modem is [TP-Link TD-W8961ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-15_TD-W8961ND.html).

Comment: If your ISP limits you they should also show you a graph of your usage! (Usually updated every 12 hours).

Comment: You can use software, you can possibly create logs. Did you read the manual, are there any options there?

Comment: My ISP does not (probably can't) give a device wise report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some routers, an alternate firmware such as DD-WRT is an option which gives some reporting options. Unfortunately, your router being an ADSL router is unsupported and therefore this cannot be done.

There won't be any reliable options with your current router, you could monitor usage per device, or look into getting an ADSL router with this functionality.

Comment: So can you suggest a router+modem that supports this and is available in India (amazon.in, flipkart.com)?

Comment: @HanitBanga - Its best if you make the decision yourself.  Research the products you are interested in, then verify they are support by firmware like DD-WRT, then make the decision based off that.  Hardware recommendations are not on topic here at Superuser.